# HTML canvas (Draw with Mouse) mouse cursor point mismatch

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to use Draw with Mouse on the canvas. The code is as follows:

```
// Stores the initial position of the cursor
let coord = {x:0 , y:0}; 

// // set a flag
let paint = false;
// Updates the coordianates of the cursor when an event e is triggered 
function getPosition(event){
  coord.x = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  coord.y = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
}
  
// The following functions toggle the flag to start and stop drawing
function startPainting(event){
    if (mouseID.checked){
    myCanvas.style.cursor = "url('/paint.cur'),auto"
    paint = true;
    getPosition(event);
    }
}

function stopPainting(){
  paint = false;
}
    
function sketch(event){
  if (!paint) return;
  ctx.beginPath();
    
  ctx.lineWidth = mouseline.value;
   
  // set to a round shape.
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
    
  ctx.strokeStyle = bcolor.value;
      
  // The cursor to start drawing
  ctx.moveTo(coord.x, coord.y);
   
  // The position of the cursor gets updated when move the mouse around.
  getPosition(event);
   
  ctx.lineTo(coord.x , coord.y);
    
  // Draws the line.
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

The problem is when I run it on my desktop the mouse is fine but on another computer, the mouse gets a mismatched position with the drawing. Can anyone help me with the issue?

Comment: Provide a proper [mre] of the issue, please. Currently we can't even tell what size your canvas has, and whether it might have been stretched by CSS.

Comment: The code you shown looks fine. Would help to see the full CSS that affects this canvas, a `transform:translate()` could mess things up or even some `padding`. I guess there could also be an issue with the custom cursor you use, might be worth testing with the default one. And seeing where these events are attached (document, or on the canvas directly) would definitely be a plus too.